# Improving time complexity for line sweep

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am solving My Calendar [I](https://leetcode.com/problems/my-calendar-i/), [II](https://leetcode.com/problems/my-calendar-ii/) and [III](https://leetcode.com/problems/my-calendar-iii/) on LeetCode.

In general, the problem statements for I and II are to determine if subsequent bookings can cause double or triple (overlapping) bookings, respectively.  I am learning the [line-sweep algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) and the code that I have come up with is as below:

```cpp
class MyCalendar {
public:
    map<int, int> m;
    
    MyCalendar() {
        m.clear();
    }
    
    bool book(int start, int end) {
        m[start]++;
        m[end]--;
        
        auto it=m.begin();
        int counter=0;
        while(it!=m.end()) {
            counter+=it->second;
            if(counter>1) {     //change to >2 for triple bookings (problem II)
                m[start]--;
                m[end]++;
                return false;
            }
            it++;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Your MyCalendar object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * MyCalendar* obj = new MyCalendar();
 * bool param_1 = obj->book(start,end);
 */
```

Similarly for problem III, we need to find the `k-booking` which happens when `k` events have some non-empty intersection (i.e., there is some time that is common to all `k` events.)  For problems I and II, the `k` values were `2` and `3`, respectively:

```cpp
class MyCalendarThree {
public:
    map<int, int> m;
    
    MyCalendarThree() {
        m.clear();
    }

    int book(int start, int end) {
        int maxval=0, counter=0;
        m[start]++; m[end]--;
        
        for(auto& each: m) {
            counter+=each.second;
            maxval=max(maxval,counter);
        }
        
        return maxval;
    }
};

/**
 * Your MyCalendarThree object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * MyCalendarThree* obj = new MyCalendarThree();
 * int param_1 = obj->book(start,end);
 */
```

All above get accepted, but my questions are: 
a. What is the time complexity for each ones above?  IMO, it is `O(n^2)`, since for each `book`ing we traverse all the `n` events in the `map` and we could have `n` calls to `book`ings. 
b. Can we do better than `O(n^2)`?

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, should there be a tag for `line-sweep` algorithm?

Comment: From the wikipedia article you linked: *The closely related Bentley–Ottmann algorithm uses a sweep line technique to report all K intersections among any N segments in the plane in time complexity of O((N + K) log N) and space complexity of O(N).[2]*

Comment: @JohnFilleau, yes, the standard algo (for detecting intersections) runs in `O((N + K) log N)`; but here I am not find the line segment intersections.

Comment: For a given iteration, you do two lookups on an ordered map, and then iterate through all current elements of the map. That's `2 (log n) + n`, multiplied by `n` calls to `book` is `2 n log n + n^2`. Which reduces to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @JohnFilleau, yep, that's what I thought, too.  Thank you for confirming.  Do you know if we could do better in this problem?

Comment: You can reduce each iteration to `2 + n` if you use an unordered map. While the complexity won't technically be less, it will practically be faster.

Comment: @JohnFilleau, we need the keys to be sorted; so I don't think we can use an `unordered_map`.

Comment: Why does it need to be sorted? You don't appear to be using the sortiness of the container at all in the shown code.

Comment: Oh wait, never mind. I see it now.

Comment: Yeah, it is a requirement of the standard line-sweep algo.  The sorted-ness is being implicitly used.

Answer (score 0):

**My suggestion:**

Keep all accepted bookings in a single sorted list containing all starting and ending times. In addition, every time has an associated counter that tells the number of bookings in the interval that follows.

Now, when you process a new booking request, find the insertion point of its starting time by binary search, and enumerate all the times until the ending of this request. If all counters remain below k, you can accept the booking.

When you accept a booking, increment the counters of all the times so covered and adjust the counters of the new booking itself.

In this example, with k=3, the green booking can be accepted, and not the red one (because it straddles the counter 3).

[image]

Comment: _"When you accept a booking, increment the counters of all the times so covered and adjust the counters of the new booking itself"_ wouldn't that increase the time complexity (make it `O(n^2)` just like my snippets)?  I actually do not see how your proposal is different to mine: `m[start]++; m[end]--;` is pretty much  incrementing/decrementing the "counters" of times covered.